# What coding tools do you use for improving effectivness of programming in FLEX?

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript

What coding tools do you use for improving effectivness of programming in FLEX?

1. I found Tr.ace() AS3 Debugging Utility which help me a lot with working in a team of programmers?
2. frameworks like RobotLegs and others.
3. Signals.

What are the others?

Chris

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess it depends how you define tools.  These are some things used by me, or others I've spoken to:

1. ServiceCapture:  This is a great program to see the packets being sent to and from the browser / Flash Player and a remote server.  Charles is another common tool for this purpose; and Flash Builder now has a network monitor built in to perform the same task.  ServiceCapture will also show the trace statements that your app puts out.
2. Step Through Debugger: The Step Through Debugger is a fantastic tool for stepping through code to figure out what happens.  It's built nicely into Flash Builder; but there is a command line tool too.  I assume that other Flex IDEs support this functionality.
3. Flash Builder: You can write code in a text editor and compile it via command line tools; but an IDE helps tremendously.  Flash Buyilder is Adobe's IDE; and the one I use primarily, but others exist such as IntelliJ or FDT.
4. ANT: ANT is build tool that allows you to do a bunch of tasks automatically; such as compiling and automatically uploading to a server.  Maven and CruiseControl are two alternate options I've heard about.  I think both are much more advanced than ANT.
5. Subversion: Subversion is a version control system that allows you to track changes with your code.  It is strongly recommended for any project; but has extra special benefits when it comes to projects with multiple people working on them.  Other options are Git, and CVS.

Comment: Thanks and waiting for more. ServiceCapture you mentioned was new to me.

Comment: [Alcon Debugger](http://www.hexagonstar.com/project/alcon/) is another favorite of mine. Just one swc install and you can see debug messages in the viewer even without the need to launch it from Flex.

Comment: Found the next one: traceDL - you can reveal the whole display list of any DisplayObject - still waiting for more...

Answer (score 1):

I would like to add some thing with "www.Flextras.com" answer.

Profiling the application

Profiling an application can help you in understanding the following:

- Call Frequency
- Method Duration
- Call Stacks
- Number of Instances and their sizes at any givin point of time
- Garbage collection and Loitering Objects

for More info refer the link
http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=profiler_1.html

since the profiling and network monitor available to premium Flash builders.

```
                   ~~~~~~~Happy Coding~~~~~~~~~
```

Answer (score 0):

There is also 
 Flexformatter: This is a great plugin for Flash Builder that helps you clean up Actionscript/MXML code.
http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/flexformatter/index.php?title=Main_Page